# Launching an activity on listitem click

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a list view something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je8Yp.jpg in activity1

Onitemselect i want to launch another acitivity which shows description about listitem1 like below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZs5r.jpg
but did not find any helpful material to create and activity with same layout to get different content like this one ::

I did explore for quite some time and I could not find any solution that helped me .

Comment: this is my first post, it would be better if you guys point out the mistake in my question rather that ranking it bad :/ .

Comment: One layout file defines how the look should be ,the question is not clear you dont want to change layout the ui behavior should change ??

Comment: Say I have a listview with 5 items, If I click on "item1" of list view it should take me to activity (lets call it activity1 ) with some content .    If I click on "item2 " it should take me to activity1 with some other content specific to item2 , and so on .

Comment: Firstly you need to implement onitemselected of listview and read about intents ,you need to fill an intent and can launch activity1

Comment: I have done onitemselected part. I want to know how the next portion of it can be done .

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(this,
                Activity1.class);
        startActivity(i);

Comment: This is to create an intent and start an activity but in my case I have multiple content based on the item i click.

Comment: Based on position you would launch and have a case statment for each position and launch activities based on the position

Comment: I do not want to create 5 different activities I want one activity and 5 different content based on the click from list view . I am sorry If I have been confusing you.

Comment: So you have only 1 activity from your listview selection .you need to pass the position to activity1 and based on that decide your content to show.fill the position in intent like this  i.putExtra("id", position);

Comment: Will definitely try that thanks @surya

Answer (score 0):

Use OnItemClickListener and use intent to open other activities on item clicks

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (i == 1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Lu1Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (i == 2) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Lu2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (i == 3) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Lu3Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (i == 4) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Lu4Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });
```

If you want to use same 2nd activity for each intent and show different content then use a global variable to know which item is selected and change content of 2nd activity as you wish.

Add a variable like this

```
public static int itemNumber;
```

Use OnItemClickListner

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            itemNumber = i;
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

In OtherActivity, Set different content to your views depending on itemNumber's value.

Note: You can also use putExtra to extend data to the intent and use that to determine which item is clicked.